# Вывод php из БД

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, база-данных

Возникла такая проблема, я хочу сделать очень динамичный сайт, в котором я могу удалять и добавлять блоки. У меня есть один большой блок, при клике на него снизу появляются ещё n-блоков. Я делаю запрос у бд на "видимый блок", а  внутри столбика в бд содержится код "видимого блока" и php-код  -  запрос на скрытые блоки 'допустим с таким же id (не первичным ключём)' . Но возникла такая проблема при выводе : html-разметка первого блока нормально выводится, а php код (который запрашивает вывод скрытых блоков),  становится закомментированным. Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приложите пример кода

Comment: Выполнено! Я ещё новичок, так что не ругайтесь на код

Comment: А можно не скриншот, а именно код

Answer (score 2):

В базе данных нельзя хранить РНР код.

PHP код должен быть написан только в PHP скриптах.
А в базе данных должны лежать только **данные**.